# How to construct measure that checks to see if data is from current month?

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
STB = 
IF ([Sales Budget] < 100,"",
DIVIDE(
    [Bookings],
    [Sales Budget] * [Adj Factor - STB MTD]
```

This is the measure as it stands. I would like to add an IF statement that checks to see if data is from a past month or if it's current. If data for the month is complete then Adj Factor is unnecessary and it should just divide [Bookings]/[Sales Budget].

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think This is something you can expect to have.

```
STB =
VAR CurrentMonth =
    MONTH ( TODAY () )
VAR Result =
    IF (
        MONTH ( YourTableName[DateColumn] ) = CurrentMonth,
        IF (
            [Sales Budget USSC PWC] < 100,
            "",
            DIVIDE ( [Bookings], [Sales Budget] * [Adj Factor - STB MTD] )
        ),
        IF ( [Sales Budget USSC PWC] < 100, "", DIVIDE ( [Bookings], [Sales Budget] ) )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Comment: Thanks! 

Would I need to add a filter in order to make sure the DIVIDE without an Adj Factor uses the Bookings and Budget totals from that particular month or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @bortplates Yes, You need to add a filter to test the measure. For example: From [DateColumn] in the slicer, select a single value not from current month. Also please do not forget to accept the solution as the answer if It solves your problem.